# A test interview question I could not figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

## So I wrote a piece of code in pycharm

to solve this problem:
pick any **5 positive integers** that add up to 100
and by **addition**,**subtraction** or just using one of the five **values**
you should be able to make **every** number up to 100
*for example*
1,22,2,3,4
for 1 I could give in 1
for 2 i could give in 2
so on
for 21 I could give 22 - 1
for 25 I could give (22 + 2) - 1

```
li = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
lists_of_li_that_pass_T1 = []
while True:
    if sum(li) == 100:
        list_of_li_that_pass_T1.append(li)
        if li[-1] != 100:
            li[-1] += 1
        else:
            li[-1] = 1
            if li[-2] != 100:
                li[-2] += 1
            else:
                li[-2] = 1
                if li[-3] != 100:
                    li[-3] += 1
                else:
                    li[-3] = 1
                    if li[-4] != 100:
                        li[-4] += 1
                    else:
                        li[-4] = 1
                        if li[-5] != 100:
                            li[-5] += 1
                        else:
                            break
    else:
        if li[-1] != 100:
            li[-1] += 1
        else:
            li[-1] = 1
            if li[-2] != 100:
                li[-2] += 1
            else:
                li[-2] = 1
                if li[-3] != 100:
                    li[-3] += 1
                else:
                    li[-3] = 1
                    if li[-4] != 100:
                        li[-4] += 1
                    else:
                        li[-4] = 1
                        if li[-5] != 100:
                            li[-5] += 1
                        else:
                            break
```

this should give me all the number combinations that add up to 100 out of the total 1*10 ** 10
but its not working please help me fix it so it prints all of the sets of integers
I also can't think of what I would do next to get the perfect sets that solve the problem

Comment: 1,22,2,3,4 do not add up to 100

Comment: The problem is ill-formed. 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 add up to 100. As all are multiple of 5, any combination using addition and substraction will be a mutiple of 5. Either the goal of the question was to see whether you were able to think of that before starting coding (is a solution always present ?), or you failed to reproduce the exact question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Where did you get the idea that all combinations using addition and subtraction should be a multiple of 5??? You need to be able to make *all* the integers from 1 to 100. The math problem is actually clear enough (though one of OP's examples is wrong, because 25 isn't the same as 22 + 2 -1). And I agree with the earlier comment that OP should have picked 5 numbers that *do* add up to 100, just to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: @JohnY: This is what I used to call a counter example in mathematics: a specific data that does not meet the expected criteria. And in integral mathematics, any addition or substraction of multiples of a common number, will be a multiple of that number.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - But we don't want *multiples* of anything. I really don't know where you are getting this idea that multiples are involved at all. We want to be able to construct **all** the integers from 1 to 100 using our set of 5 positive integers. To take OP's (poorly chosen) set of 5: We can construct 1, 2, 3, 4, and 22 trivially. We can construct 5 as (4 + 1). We can construct 6 as (4 + 2). 7 as (4 + 3). 8 as (4 + 3 + 1). To jump ahead, we can make 18 as (22 - 4), 19 as (22 - 3), 20 as (22 - 2). Not all constructions will be unique.

Comment: @JohnY: English is not my first language, but question states that it should work for **any** set of 5 numbers summing up to 100. I just say for for a specific set it does not work. It is easy to find a set that trivially works: just put 1 in it and you'll get any number: 1,2,3,4,90 ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta - The English in the question could have been better. The math problem is to find *some* set of 5 positive integers which satisfies the following two requirements: First, they must add up to 100. Second, you must be able to construct all the integers from 1 to 100 using addition and subtraction of that set of 5, with each member of the set appearing at most once in any given construction.

Comment: @JohnY: your question is nice, clear and non ambiguous. And my comments are absolutely irrelevant with it. But even after reading it again and again I cannot understand that what OP asked is that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @JohnY comments, I assume that the question is:

> Find a set of 5 integers meeting the following requirements:
>
> - their sum is 100
> - any number in the [1, 100] range can be constructed using at most once the elements of the set and only additions and substractions

A brute force way is certainly possible, but proving that any number can be constructed that way would be tedious. But a divide and conquer strategy is possible: to construct all numbers up to n with a set of m numbers u<sub>0</sub>...,  u<sub>m-1</sub>, it is enough to build all numbers up to (n+2)/3 with u<sub>0</sub>...,  u<sub>m-2</sub> and use u<sub>m-1</sub> = 2*n/3. Any number in the ((n+2)/3, u<sub>m-1</sub>) range can be written as u<sub>m-1</sub>-x with x in the [1, (n+2)/3] range, and any number in the (u<sub>m-1</sub>, n] range as u<sub>m-1</sub>+y with y in the same low range.

So we can use here u<sub>4</sub> = 66 and find a way to build numbers up to 34 with 4 numbers.

Let us iterate: u<sub>3</sub> = 24 and build numbers up to 12 with 3 numbers.

One more step u<sub>2</sub> = 8 and build numbers up to 4 with 2 numbers.

Ok: u<sub>0</sub> = 1 and u<sub>1</sub> = 3 give immediately:

- 1 = u<sub>0</sub>
- 2 = 3 - 1 = u<sub>1</sub> - u<sub>0</sub>
- 3 = u<sub>1</sub>
- 4 = 3 + 1 = u<sub>1</sub> + u<sub>0</sub>

Done.

---

Mathematical disgression:

In fact u<sub>0</sub> = 1 and u<sub>1</sub> = 3 can build all numbers up to 4, so we can use u<sub>2</sub> = 9 to build all numbers up to 9+4 = 13. We can prove easily that the sequence u<sub>i</sub> = 3<sup>i</sup> verifies sum(u<sub>i</sub> for i in [0, m-1]) = 1 + 3 + ... + 3<sup>m-1</sup> = (3<sup>m</sup> - 1)/(3 - 1) = (u<sub>m</sub> - 1) / 2.

So we could use u<sub>0</sub>=1, u<sub>1</sub>=3, u<sub>2</sub>=9, u<sub>3</sub>=27 to build all numbers up to 40, and finally set u<sub>4</sub> = 60.

In fact, u<sub>0</sub> and u<sub>1</sub> can only be 1 and 3 and u<sub>2</sub> can be 8 or 9. Then if u<sub>2</sub> == 8, u<sub>3</sub> can be in the [22, 25] range, and if u<sub>2</sub> == 9, u<sub>3</sub> can be in the [21, 27] range. The high limit is given by the 3<sup>i</sup> sequence, and the low limit is given by the requirement to build numbers up to 12 with 3 numbers, and up to 34 with 4 ones.

No code was used, but I think that way much quicker and less error prone. It is now possible to use Python to show that all numbers up to 100 can be constructed from one of those sets using the divide and conquer strategy.